# Cannot find User Interface Code Sample from a 2009 Mac WWDC session

Tags: cocoa, macos, wwdc

The Session 426 "state of the art cocoa - user interface design" (MAC session) is really helpful.
The title of the code sample used during the session is "Exposure".
I cannot find it in the Mac Dev Center.

Can you say me if the example is available on ADC website?

Thanks.

Comment: Discussion of exact WWDC session content might be considered a violation of the NDA with Apple on that content.  I'd recommend asking in Apple's own forums: https://devforums.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

Go to [the WWDC attendee site](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/attendee/), then follow the link to ADC on iTunes. Log in with the Apple ID you used for WWDC. Once iTunes opens to the ADC on iTunes page, you may be able to find it there.